# Problem simulating transistor on Proteus

Tags: transistors, pnp, proteus, 7segmentdisplay

I'm using PNP transistor to be a switch for CC pin of 7Segment (Common Anode) led and trying simulating it on Proteus at first. Something weird happens is that no matter high or low level at B gate, the voltage at E keeps being high level and just reciprocally changed between about 2V5 and 5V. Therefore, all 7SEGs are always enabled at the same time, and not able to display accurately. I added a pull-down resistor for each Collector and saw it working properly. I wonder why almost of the example on the Internet design the same one without using pull-down resistor but it still works. Does the problem result from Proteus and it's unnecessary to use these resistors in reality? Hope someone used to have this problem could help me figure it out. I've updated my circuit below:
[image]

Comment: Is that ground on the collector or something else?

Comment: Collector is connected to 5V

Comment: Your transistor is upside-down.  The arrow in transistors points toward the negative supply. The emitter of a PNP transistor should be connected to the positive supply.  What is the High voltage level at the input?

Comment: The input should be 5V. I followed your direction and Collector is at 3V3 when it’s High level at B gate.

Comment: After you correct the transistor orientation, the collector will only go Low if you connect a pull-down resistor from collector to ground.  In your circui there is nothing to pull the collector down.

Comment: Yeah, I did and it worked. But there are many example of using PNP for sweeping 7Segment without connecting pull-down resistor and it still works, at least in reality. So does the problem comes with Proteus?

Comment: The LEDs in the displays will act (to some extent) as a pull-down load - you need some load on the collector to see a voltage swing there.

Comment: Nothing changed even if I connect the collector output to load (CC pin of 7 segments), the result is constantly at a high level(5V and 3v3)

Comment: @STUDENTSTRANGE Your initial question regarding the simulation was resolved.  Now you are proceeding to troubleshooting your physical circuit, so it requires more details such as a complete schematic of your circuit.  Either make a new question or edit this one with the proper information.

Comment: @SteKulov Thank you, I edited it for more details as you said.

Comment: @STUDENTSTRANGE Is there a part number for the 7-segment display?

Comment: The two 7-segment was enabled at the same time and just showed the digit established for the first one. I mean if the code makes 8 display at the first and 9 for the second one, both of them will display simultaneously 8 digit

Comment: @STUDENTSTRANGE I meant a part# for the actual display...like a model number such as [LTD-6940HR](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/lite-on-inc/LTD-6940HR/3199144).  I guess it doesn't matter since it sounds like you are having software issues now.  Since both characters light up then both transistors are operational.  You shouldn't need the pulldown resistors in real life.  They were only emulating the display in the original simulation.